# ¿Cómo agregar el idioma chino en HTML?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando agregar el abecedario Chino a mi pagina de HTML, pero no puedo generar el idioma correctamente, estoy intentando utilizar la etiqueta `<html lang="zh">`, pero aun me genera error sacando estos caracteres

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error parece ser de que el `content-type` no es el correcto. Deberías chequear las siguiente cosas:

- Tener en el `<head>` el siguiente meta: `<meta charset="utf-8">` o la versión larga: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
- Chequear que el archivo dónde estás insertando el texto en chino esté en la misma codificación `UTF-8`.

Comment: Si estoy manejando el meta:  <meta charset="utf-8"> y ya confirme que la codificación del archivo este en  UTF-8, pero aun se presenta el error

Comment: @alec_ por favor edita tu pregunta agregando el html que tienes. Según este [comentario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670034/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-html#comment30950322_20670034), el archivo que contiene el HTML debe estár también en `UTF-8`.